# how can I fix drawer transparency problem in native base

Tags: transparency, opacity, drawer

I used native base code of drawer to make a sidebar for my home page, the button works fine I used on press as `this.openDrawer()`. I am using this code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Drawer, Header, Icon, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';
import { Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import SideBar from '../screens/sidebar';

export default class home extends Component {
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Icon name="menu" style={{ color: '#fff' }}
              onPress={() => this.openDrawer()}
            />
          </Left>
          <Body style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Welcome to app!</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right></Right>
        </Header>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

[Sidebar opacity is less. check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIHhd.png)

I wonder why its opacity is less, I have tried giving a background color to white in my sidebar screen. Please help , anyone with native base?